# glog always create two files, which has nearly the same content

Tags: glog

My test code as blow:

```
std::string strLogPath = "d:/logtest/";
google::InitGoogleLogging("test1");
FLAGS_log_dir = strLogPath;
FLAGS_stderrthreshold = google::GLOG_INFO;
FLAGS_minloglevel = google::GLOG_INFO;
//FLAGS_colorlogtostderr = true;

std::string strLogPath1 = "d:/logtest/L";
google::SetLogDestination(google::GLOG_INFO, strLogPath1.c_str()); 
google::SetLogDestination(google::GLOG_ERROR, strLogPath1.c_str());
google::SetLogDestination(google::GLOG_WARNING, strLogPath1.c_str());
google::SetLogDestination(google::GLOG_FATAL, strLogPath1.c_str());

LOG(INFO) << "infoinfo";
Sleep(1000);
LOG(WARNING) << "wwwww";
LOG(WARNING) << "wwwww";
LOG(ERROR) << "eeeeee";
Sleep(2000);
//LOG(FATAL) << "ffffff";
LOG(WARNING) << "wwwww";
LOG(WARNING) << "wwwww";
LOG(WARNING) << "wwwww";
google::ShutdownGoogleLogging();
```

I got two log files, one file contain all messages(INFO, WARNING and ERROR), and the other contain all WARNING and ERROR messages, but without INFO. This is quiet different from my expectation. I want **all messages in one file**, and don't like the WARNING and ERROR messages appear twice in different files.
It would be highly appreciated if someone can tell me the solution. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have a solution for your problem but I will post this anyway for other users.

---

glog is not designed for logging in one file as far as I know. Therefore you can't do what you want using only glog.

However there are other solutions for your problem.

**First**: Write your own little logging library. This isn't very complicated and is a great Programming training ;)

**Second**: For *nix only. Activate logging to stderr in glog using the logtostderr-Flag and redirect the output from stderr to the desired log file.

```
FLAGS_logtostderr=1;
LOG(INFO) << "Info";
LOG(WARNING) << "Warning";
LOG(ERROR) << "Error";
```

and on the shell: `./MyProg 2>logFile`

**Last**: Keep everything as it is and delete the logfiles you don't need. Either within your program using c/c++ or with a call to `system()`